# How to know how I installed Node on macOS?

Tags: macos, installation, command-line, zsh

I know that I have Node installed but I don't remember if I used NVM, Brew or if I downloaded it from the official Node website.
Is there any command I can use to figure out how I installed it in the first place?

Note: I use a zsh shell on macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good indicator is to check where it is installed:

```
ls -l $(which node)
```

For brew, this will yield something like

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 flyx  admin  30 Sep 12 17:02 /usr/local/bin/node -> ../Cellar/node/16.9.1/bin/node
```

NVM seems to install it somewhere in `~/.nvm` but I don't know the specifics. I have no idea what the installer does.

Comment: I just noticed that `$ which node` would have been sufficient to know it was via nvm.

Comment: Yes, `ls -l` doesn't hurt though. I've thrown it in for the case of `/usr/local/bin`, which is less clear.